# Arcpy New Mosaic to New Raster script error

Tags: arcpy, mosaic, error-000582

I wrote a script to Merge Raster files, but unfortunately scripts does not work:

```
import arcpy  
import os  

workspace = "D:\Kartes\Ortofoto_published\2400"  
sr = "D:\Maris\Salni\CoordinateSystem\LKS 1992 Latvia TM.prj"


rasters = []  
walk = arcpy.da.Walk(workspace, topdown=True, datatype="RasterDataset")  
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in walk:  
    for filename in filenames:  
        rasters.append(os.path.join(dirpath, filename))  

ras_list = ";".join(rasters)  
arcpy.MosaicToNewRaster_management(ras_list,"D:\Kartes\Ortofoto_published", "newraster", sr, "8_BIT_UNSIGNED", "1000", "3", "LAST","FIRST")
```

Show error (ERROR 000582: Error occurred during execution)

Comment: Here is second script :(

Comment: import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = r"D:\Kartes\Ortofoto_published\2400"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

outPut = r"D:\Kartes\Ortofoto_published"
name = "2400.tif"
sr = r"D:\Maris\Salni\CoordinateSystem\LKS 1992 Latvia TM.prj"
bands = 3
method = "LAST"
clMap = "First"

rasters = arcpy.ListRasters()

arcpy.MosaicToNewRaster_management(2400, outPut, name, sr, "8_BIT_UNSIGNED", "", bands, method, clMap)

Comment: Welcome to GIS.SE! Rather then adding information by comments, it is better to edit your answer, and give more information there.